# Insert values from 1 form into 2 sql server tables (PHP) (SQL-Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

I want to use one form to insert into two different Microsoft sql tables. I tryed to use 2 inserts, but didnt work.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
                $sth = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Fehler (QualiID, TestaufstellungID, ModulinfoID, failAfter, Datum, Verbleib, DUTNr) VALUES ($QualiID, $TestaufstellungID,$ModulinfoID,'$failAfter','$Datum','$Verbleib','$DUTNr')");
                        echo "INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Fehler (QualiID, TestaufstellungID, ModulinfoID, failAfter, Datum, Verbleib, DUTNr) VALUES ($QualiID, $TestaufstellungID,$ModulinfoID,'$failAfter',$Datum,'$Verbleib','$DUTNr')";
                        $sth->execute();

                    if($sth)
                        {
                            echo "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo sqlsrv_errors();
                        }

$MID = $connection->prepare("MAX(MID) as MID FROM DB.dbo.Fehler WHERE DB.dbo.Fehler.TestaufstellungID = '". $TestaufstellungID . "'");
$MID->execute();

$sth2 = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo (MID, Tester, Test, Ausfallbedingungen, Fehlerbeschreibung, Ersteller) VALUES ($MID, '$Tester','$Test','$Ausfallbedingungen','$Fehlerbeschreibung','$Ersteller')");
$sth2->execute();
```

To understand *MID* is the Primary key of table *Fehler* and ist the foreign key in the second table *Fehlerinfo*

Thats why i have the select work around to get the last MID and want to save it in a variable $MID to insert it into the second table.

Is there a smarter solution possible?

Comment: Why not do it all in the same batch instead and have SQL Server handle it all there?

Comment: when i manullay do it 1by1 in a SQL query it works on Server side. Dunno how i can do it in one Batch if i dont have the actual last MID for the second table. I can Insert a Null and than Update the MID foreignkey maybe afterwards.

Comment: The problem with what you're doing here is you also have the possibility of race conditions; in that 2 `INSERT` statements could be run again your Primary table, and before the `SELECT` runs. I don't completely understand your code though, I'm afraid (especially the PHP, which seems incomplete to me, but I don't write it often). I'll post an example of a single batch process in T-SQL for you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned the answer how it works for me fine atm.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$failInsert = ("INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Fehler (QualiID, TestaufstellungID, ModulinfoID, failAfter, Datum, Verbleib, DUTNr) VALUES ($QualiID, $TestaufstellungID,$ModulinfoID,'$failAfter','$Datum','$Verbleib','$DUTNr')");
$failInsert .= ("INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo (MID, Tester, Test, Ausfallbedingungen, Fehlerbeschreibung, Ersteller) VALUES (NULL, '$Tester','$Test','$Ausfallbedingungen','$Fehlerbeschreibung','$Ersteller')");
$failInsert .= ("UPDATE DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo SET DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo.MID = i.MID FROM (SELECT MAX(MID)as MID FROM DB.dbo.Fehler) i WHERE DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo.TestID = ( SELECT MAX(TestID) as TestID FROM DB.dbo.Fehlerinfo)"); 
$sth = $connection->prepare($failInsert);

$sth->execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, generally the better way is to do the insert in one batch. This is very over simplified, however, should put you in the right direction. Normally you would likely be passing the values for the Foreign Table in a Table Value Parameter (due to the Many to One relationship) and would encapsulate the entire thing in a `TRY...CATCH` and possibly a stored procedure.

I can't write this in PHP, as my knowledge of it is rudimentary, but this should get you on the right path to understanding:

```
USE Sandbox;

--Couple of sample tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.PrimaryTable (SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                               SomeString varchar(10),
                               CONSTRAINT PK_PTID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (SomeID));

CREATE TABLE dbo.ForeignTable (AnotherID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                               ForeignID int,
                               AnotherString varchar(10),
                               CONSTRAINT PK_FTID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(AnotherID),
                               CONSTRAINT FK_FTPT FOREIGN KEY (ForeignID)
                                  REFERENCES dbo.PrimaryTable(SomeID));

GO

--single batch example

--Declare input parameters and give some values
--These would be the values coming from your application
DECLARE @SomeString varchar(10) = 'abc',
        @AnotherString varchar(10) = 'def';

--Create a temp table or variable for the output of the ID
DECLARE @ID table (ID int);

--Insert the data and get the ID at the same time:
INSERT INTO dbo.PrimaryTable (SomeString)
OUTPUT inserted.SomeID
INTO @ID
SELECT @SomeString;

--@ID now has the inserted ID(s)
--Use it to insert into the other table
INSERT INTO dbo.ForeignTable (ForeignID,AnotherString)
SELECT ID,
       @AnotherString
FROM @ID;
GO

--Check the data:

SELECT *
FROM dbo.PrimaryTable PT
     JOIN dbo.ForeignTable FT ON PT.SomeID = FT.ForeignID;
GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.ForeignTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.PrimaryTable;
```

Comment: My knowledge is rudimentary about T-SQL i have no idea how to implement it in PHP. But i solved my Problem in a other dirty way. Look at the Post.